# Adding ghcr (Github Docker Regustry) to Synology docker results in "Registry returned bad result"

Tags: docker, github, synology, ghcr, github-container-registry

When trying to add the Github Registry to Synology Docker, I always get a prompt saying "Registry returned bad result".

The URL I try to connect to is: `https://ghcr.io`

Answer (score 14):

I'm trying to do the same (DS920+, DSM 7.1 latest). According to this Reddit:

https://www.reddit.com/r/portainer/comments/u1vf1s/how_to_add_ghcr_as_a_registry/

it used to work with 'docker.pkg.github.com' as the repo url, but according to the current Github docs, it was the old namespace and the actual repo is now 'https://ghcr.io'

https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-container-registry

According to the docs, authentication is implied many times, maybe it is not possible to use the repo w/o authentication (tried with access tokens, not working).

I opened a Synology support ticket, let's see what they can say.

2022-10-27 - Synology Support replied and the official statement is that the token authentication currently used by Github Container Registry is not supported on the DSM's Docker package GUI. Its possible to ssh to the DSM and use docker from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

As an addendum to what Peter mentioned. You can workaround this issue by enabling SSH Terminal on your NAS, logging in and then running these commands:

1. You can either run docker as sudo or [add your user to the docker group and allow that group access to the /var/run/docker.sock](https://superuser.com/questions/1545551/give-permission-to-acces-var-run-docker-sock-on-synology-nas). (In my case this didn't work for some reason, so I just used sudo.) Make sure to log out and back in for the permissions to take effect.
2. Then pull the image you want from ghcr.io. In my case this command was:

> docker pull ghcr.io/home-assistant-libs/python-matter-server:5.5.3

3. Afterward, you will see the image in the GUI of Container Manager.